# Laptop stuck on dell logo, not booting the ubuntu

Tags: boot, dell

I had normally turned of my laptop and it is not loading at the moment. It got stuck on dell logo.

What I have done so far:

1. Run diagnostic and no hardware issue detected. Just two other issue `battery coming to an end of usable life` and `fan running faster than normal speed.`

2)on boot options it shows two options: ubuntu and sata drive. When i try to boot from ubuntu it just got stuck and when i try from that sata drive it says: `Sytem boot order not found. Initializing defaults.`

What is the best and safest way to deal with this scenario? I have dell 5570 with M2 ssd and 2TB hdd on my laptop. M2 ssd is the one where i have installed ububtu

I am from mobile, so please consider typo if there are any that i might have missed.

Answer (score -1):

Try booting form a Live USB stick. Details can be found on https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: This looks like the new installation you are recommending. Isn't there some other way.

Comment: Only if it was able to open shell. Not anything unless it stuck. You might have some hardware problem. If you press the function keys, you might get some logs. There something you should see.